# Why does Bridging edges not work as it should

Tags: mesh

I select all the edges of the cylinder and then all the edges of the outer shape, when I try to bridge the edges of the cylinder with the edges of the outer shape I get this, what am I doing wrong ?

Delete loos, Merge by distance, Face orientation, Scale, Recalculate normals, I've done them all.

[image: Bridging with edges]

Comment: It may be because you have different number of vertices on each loop

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were trying to bridge two sets of edge loops at the same time. Do the sets one at a time, because otherwise Blender will think it’s supposed to connect them all in sequence as one single-face-thick tube. From the looks of your geometry, that is what happened, and the results are expectedly weird.